# Looping via array without using property

Tags: javascript

I have a data which goes something like this

```
var data =  [{"empid":1},{"empid":2},{"empid":3},{"empid":4},{"empid":5},{"empid":6},{"empid":7},{"empid":8},{"empid":9}]
```

when I try to iterate over it using Javascript, the value which is returned is another object.

I am trying to do something like this

```
for (var key in data) {
    console.log(' name=' + key + ' value=' + data[key]);

}
```

I expected to see my empid values as part of 'value' in the log but the 'value' is another object array.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sourabhtewari/b6b3qxo7/

Note: I cannot use property name to fetch the value as the data would be dynamic. So I cant do something like `JSON.stringify(data[key].empid)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over the array, and you don't do that with `for..in`, but with a regular for-loop, inside which you may use `for..in` because each array item is an object:

```
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    for (var key in data[i]) {
        console.log(' name=' + key + ' value=' + data[i][key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call the property of it.

```
data[key].empid
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/b6b3qxo7/1/) a working example.

Answer (score 0):

You should never use `for in` for arrays, that iterates over *object properties*.

Use

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   // ..
}
```

instead. You can access the value will in the loop as `data[i].empid`.

Comment: This is going to be slow because JavaScript is going to evaluate length property every iteration :)

Comment: Or not! Modern browsers can cache it. In older browser, you can do this yourselft, but it makes the code less clear.

Comment: @RGraham, check reversed loop and iteration process that occurs when you access the length property of an array in JavaScript #basics101

Comment: @AllanChua I know all about it and I often cache length myself, but calling it *slow* is a gross exaggeration. That's a micro-optimisation at best and can be safely omitted from a Stack Overflow answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're converting an Object to a string, if you just call the `empid` property you'll see the value:

```
for (var key in data) {
    console.log(' name=' + key + ' value=' + data[key].empid);
}
```

You can also use other functions to iterate on arrays though, with map you can retrieve your properties and store them in another array:

```
values = data.map( function(element) {
    return element.empid;
}
// values will be an array with all the empid properties
```

Or `Array.forEach()`:

```
data.forEach(function (element) {
     console.log(element.empid);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it's an array and it's numeric, you could look at your code as such:

```
var data =  [{"empid":1},{"empid":2},{"empid":3},...];
var data = {0: {"empid":1}, 1:{"empid":2}, {"empid":3}, ...}
```

When using a for...in loop, you are actually assigning the numerical value to your `key`, looping through all keys, but thats not what you want. When you ask for the value in that circumstance, you will get back the object assigned to that key! There are two ways you can do this. First, by modifying your code:

```
for (var key in data) {
    console.log(' name=' + key + ' value=' + data[key].empid);
}
```

Or by using the proper way to loop through an array using a regular `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; o < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(' name=' + i + ' value=' + data[i].empid);
}
```